# Declare known element inside an unknown element in an XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm creating an XML schema describing an aggregate of XML from various sources. These sources have various/unknown element names, yet I'd like to validate a known, common child element.

E.g:

```
<foo>
    <common bar="bar" />
</foo>

<baz>
    <common bar="bar" />
</baz>
```

I'd like to describe the `common` element with a required argument `bar`, but without knowing the name of the parent element (`foo` and `baz` in the example, but could be anything in reality)

I have the following, but don't know how to enforce a `common` element inside any element.

```
<xs:complexType name="vendor">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The W3C docs tell me you can't place a `xs:sequence` tag inside an `xs:any` tag, so I have no clue on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, this is not achievable with XSD 1.0; that is unless:
- the common element is always the first element, in which case you set that element first, then follow it by xsd:any as needed
- the common element is in a namespace that can be singled out relative to the namespace clause expressible with xsd:any considering your namespaces, in which case you can use an arbitrary number of xsd:any before and after such a mandatory `common` instance.

Alternatively, if you leave minOccurs=1, set the processContents to lax, and ensure that the schema for `common` is available to the XSD processor during validation, then one can at least guarantee, should a `common` occur, that it is valid. Unfortunately, you cannot guarantee it will be there at least once.

If none of the above would work for you, then you could easily define a Schematron adjunct to your XSD 1.0; this should work if you can afford an XSLT run.

Lastly, if XSD 1.1 is an option, a simple assert would do exactly what you need. The problem is that XSD 1.1 is still in its infancy, when it comes to support.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going for the "Alternatively, if..." approach.

Answer (score 0):

First, define a schema declaring the common element `common`.

Then, invoke your schema validator on the `common` elements in your document, instead of on the document's outermost element.  This will work only if your validator allows you to say where to start validation; most validators made available with an API can do this, but many command-line interfaces don't support it (they should, perhaps, but they don't).

Or alternatively, invoke your schema validator on the outermost document element in 'lax wildcard mode'; this is (as far as I can tell) the most common default invocation mode for command-line interfaces.  This will work only if your validator handles lax wildcards by descending to the children (and then grand-children, and then further ...) of the element matching the wildcard, seeking to validate them recursively.  (This behavior is optional in XSD 1.0, but widely implemented.)